# jquery validation is working but no validation message

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

I am working on a website using a purchased theme from wrapbootstrap and working specifically with its CONTACT FORM.

You can check the demo of the contact form here: [CONTACT FORM DEMO](http://gridelicious.com/themes/treble/demo/#page-contact)

The form is using validation that shows the floating message when the input is not as expected.

the original html code for the form is just plain as below:

```
<form>
      <input type="text" class="span12" placeholder="Title" required="required">
      <input type="email" class="span12" placeholder="Email" required="required">
      <textarea rows="10" class="span12" required="required"></textarea>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

then I changed the codes for my need and the validation stopped showing the messages but I am sure the validation in the background is working. I can see from the red highlight and the form is not submitted.

here is the customized code of mine:

```
<form>
      <input id="message-title" type="text" class="span12" placeholder="Name" required="required">
      <input id="message-email" type="email" class="span12" placeholder="Email" required="required">
      <textarea id="message-content" rows="10" class="span12" required="required"></textarea>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary SendMessage">Submit</button>
</form>
```

What could be the problem that caused this?

FYI: I am working in asp MVC 5 web site. So I am editing the HTML in razor view. I use the submit button in the form above to submit ajax request to one of my controllers.

My SHORTCOMING: I am not good at javascript. I have been trying to find a javascript piece that controls the validation of the form, but I could not find it. If you guys check the source code of the [CONTACT FORM DEMO](http://gridelicious.com/themes/treble/demo/#page-contact), there is no jquery validation embedded.

From all of the javascript documents embeded in the website, I am only suspicious for this one document. Lemme show the whole code below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
/**
*   Global variables.
*/
var pageHeight = $(window).height();
var pageWidth = $(window).width();
var navigationHeight = $("#navigation").outerHeight();

/**
*   ON RESIZE, check again
*/
$(window).resize(function () {
    pageWidth = $(window).width();
    pageHeight = $(window).height();
});


/**
*   ON LOAD
*/

/* Initialize scroll so if user droped to other part of page then home page. */
$(window).trigger('scroll');

/* Fix navigation. */
$('#navigation').fixedonlater({
    speedDown: 250,
    speedUp: 100
});

/* Centralize elements on page. */
$('.centralized').centralized({
    delay: 1500,
    fadeSpeed: 500
});

/* Make embeded videos responsive. */
$.fn.responsivevideos();

/* Carousel "Quote slider" initialization. */
$('#quote-slider').each(function(){
    if($('.item', this).length) {
        $(this).carousel({
            interval: 20000
        });
    }
});

/* Scroll spy and scroll filter */
$('#main-menu').onePageNav({
    currentClass: "active",
    changeHash: false,
    scrollOffset: navigationHeight - 10,
    scrollThreshold: 0.5,
    scrollSpeed: 750,
    filter: "",
    easing: "swing"
 });

/* 
*  Paralax initialization.
*  Exclude for mobile.
*/
if(pageWidth > 980){
    /* Dont user paralax for tablet and mobile devices. */
    $('#page-welcome').parallax("0%", 0.2);
    $('#page-features').parallax("0%", 0.07);
    $('#page-twitter').parallax("0%", 0.1);
}

/* Emulate touch on table/mobile touchstart. */
if(typeof(window.ontouchstart) != 'undefined') {
    var touchElements = [".social-icons a", ".portfolio-items li", ".about-items .item"];

    $.each(touchElements, function (i, val) {
        $(val).each(function(i, obj) {
            $(obj).bind('click', function(e){

                if($(this).hasClass('clickInNext')){
                    $(this).removeClass('clickInNext');
                } else {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    e.stopPropagation();

                    $(this).mouseover();
                    $(this).addClass('clickInNext');
                }
            });
        });
    });
}

/**
*   BLOCK | Navigation
*
*   Smooth scroll
*   Main menu links
*   Logo click on Welcome page
*/
$('#page-welcome .logo a').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top - navigationHeight + 4
    }, 800);

    /* Fix jumping of navigation. */
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(window).trigger('scroll');
    }, 900);

    return false;
});

/**
*   PAGE | Welcome 
*
*   Initialize slider for welcome page H1 message.
*/
$('#welcome-messages ul').bxSlider({
    mode: 'vertical',
    auto: true,
    minSlides: 1,
    responsive: true,
    touchEnabled: true,
    pager: false,
    controls: false,
    useCSS: false,
    pause: 10000
});

/**
*   PAGE | WORK
*
*   .plugin-filter - Defines action links.
*   .plugin-filter-elements - Defines items with li.
*/
$('.plugin-filter').click(function(){
    return false;
});
$('.plugin-filter-elements').mixitup({
    targetSelector: '.mix',
    filterSelector: '.plugin-filter',
    sortSelector: '.sort',
    buttonEvent: 'click',
    effects: ['fade','rotateY'],
    listEffects: null,
    easing: 'smooth',
    layoutMode: 'grid',
    targetDisplayGrid: 'inline-block',
    targetDisplayList: 'block',
    gridClass: '',
    listClass: '',
    transitionSpeed: 600,
    showOnLoad: 'all',
    sortOnLoad: false,
    multiFilter: false,
    filterLogic: 'or',
    resizeContainer: true,
    minHeight: 0,
    failClass: 'fail',
    perspectiveDistance: '3000',
    perspectiveOrigin: '50% 50%',
    animateGridList: true,
    onMixLoad: null,
    onMixStart: null,
    onMixEnd: null
});

/**
*   PAGE | Twitter 
*
*   Pull latest tweets from user.
*   Configuration: /plugins/twitter/index.php
*/
$('#twitterfeed-slider').tweet({
    modpath: 'plugins/twitter/',
    username: 'TheGridelicious',
    count: 3
});

$('#twitterfeed-slider').tweetCarousel({
    interval: 7000,
    pause: "hover"
});
});


/**
*   Ajax request.
*   Start loading.
*   Append loading notification.
*/
$( document ).ajaxSend( function() {
/* Show loader. */
if($(".loading").length == 0) {
    $("body").append('<div class="loading"><div class="progress progress-striped active"><div class="bar"></div></div></div>');
    $(".loading").slideDown();
    $(".loading .progress .bar").delay(300).css("width", "100%");
}
});

/**
*   Reinitialize Scrollspy after ajax request is completed.
*   Refreshing will recalculate positions of each page in document.
*   Time delay is added to allow ajax loaded content to expand and change height of page.
*/
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
/* Remove loading section. */
$(".loading").delay(1000).slideUp(500, function(){
    $(this).remove();
});

/* Portfolio details - close. */
$(".close-portfolio span").click(function(e) {
    $(".portfolio-item-details").delay(500).slideUp(500, function(){
        $(this).remove();
    });

    window.location.hash= "!";
    return false;
});
});
```

Please have a look and tell me if the setting is somewhere in this document, even though I dont think so, according to my knowledge which could be wrong.

Please inform me other possibilities source for this problem. thanks